# Matlab Sum values using timestamps as an vector index

Tags: matlab, indexing, time-series

I have a matrix A which includes timeseries [:,1:end-1] and at its last column has hourly time-stamps [0:23].

I would like to sum the values between specific hours [0:4], [4:8]

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Use some actual sample data for `timeseries` and show us the expected output, if possible?

Comment: A=[94.7 0.8 1.7 0
94.3 0.8 1.7 1
94.3 0.8 1.7 2
94.1 0.8 1.7 3
94.1 0.8 1.7 4
94.3 0.8 1.7 5
94.4 0.8 1.7 6
94.5 0.8 1.7 7
94.5 0.8 1.7 8
94.6 0.8 1.7 15
94.6 0.8 1.7 16
94.6 0.8 1.7 18
94.6 0.8 1.7 19
94.6 0.8 1.7 20
94.7 0.8 1.7 21
94.7 0.8 1.7 22
94.7 0.8 1.7 23
94.7 0.8 1.7 0
94.7 0.8 1.7 1
94.7 0.8 1.7 2
94.8 0.8 1.7 3
94.7 0.8 1.7 4
94.8 0.8 1.7 5
94.8 0.8 1.7 6
94.8 0.8 1.7 7
] expected Out=[376.8 3.2 6.7
378.9 3.2 6.7]

Comment: Sorry for the format! The output is only for [1:4]

Comment: To be more specific I want to sum up timeseries per time bucket

Comment: The matrices A and out should not be in a comment. A general way to think is **"Every clarification to a comment should be done by editing the question."**. Otherwise. One way to solve the problem could be by rounding the timestamp to "bucket size" and then use `accumarray`. An other way could be to use `histc` to find an increment large enough to fit in the next "bucket".